# PDE plugin for Eclipse - which repository to install from?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I'd like to install the PDE plugin for Eclipse (3.7)

I cannot find a working repository... Could you tell me how I can install this plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Help > Install new software`.

You should have http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo as an update site by default. Select it (or add it if you don't). Select `General Purpose Tools > Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment` and install it. Eclipse will automatically find any dependencies.