# How do I install the PDE eclipse plugin for Eclipse 3.8.2

Tags: eclipse

There's a link here... but this is Indigo:
[PDE plugin for Eclipse - which repository to install from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480274/pde-plugin-for-eclipse-which-repository-to-install-from)

Here's a link to the zip file...
http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.8.2-201301310800/#PDESDK

... but extracting it in the plugin directory doesn't work... and I'm afraid to explode out the files amongst the other /plugins, /features and / because I can't afford to break my build of eclipse. Also there are two top level jars in the zip and it doesn't feel right that they sit in the main directory (artifacts.jar and contents.jar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an install repository which you install using 'Install New Software'.

Click the 'Add...' button in the Available Software dialog. In pop-up Add Repository dialog click 'Archive' and select the download (or use 'Local' if you have expanded the download).

You may need to untick "Group items by category" if you get message stating that there are "There are no categorized items".

Note that many Eclipse installs come with PDE included.

Comment: Adding the above link as an install repository results in a failure. It appears that it isn't such.

Comment: Just to note that generally update sites don't have "download" in their path. "release" and "update" seem common

Comment: Yes but the zip you download may be useable as a local update site.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! This seems to be working. You may want to update your answer to say that you need to untick "Group items by category" or it comes up with no options stating "There are no categorized items".